# Syntax error in MySQL: trying to create a table using varchar

Tags: mysql

This is the code I am trying to write out. It takes me that the varchar on the third line is wrong- error message says varchar is not valid at this position, expecting '('.

Create table EBook (
BookID int(6), primary key
Title **varchar**(45)
Primary_Author char(20)
Secondary_Author char(20)
Date_of_Publication varchar(10)
Page_Number int(3)
Publisher char(20)
Translator char(20)
Genre varchar(12)
Topics varchar(20)
);

Help!

Comment: you need commas between column definitions (and to read the manual,course notes)

Comment: When in doubt: use mysqldump to show the structure of some other table as a real-world example/template. Excellent learning resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how your create table should look like:

```
CREATE TABLE EBook (
BookID INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
Primary_author VARCHAR(20),
Secondary_author VARCHAR(20),
Date_of_publication VARCHAR(10),
Page_number int(3),
Publisher VARCHAR(20),
Translator VARCHAR(20),
Genre VARCHAR(12),
Topics VARCHAR(20)
);
```

You can check [Create Table syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create_table.asp) here.